# Can I get aggregated value of Mindful Minutes from Healthkit?

Tags: ios, healthkit

For an `HKQuantityType` like Steps, the `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` can be used to get the aggregated value of Steps since HealthKit itself handles it. But Mindful Minutes is an `HKCategoryType` and from what I know `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` doesn't support this type.

So how do I fetch the aggregated value that is displayed on the Health app's dashboard when "Mindfulness" is tapped? Is there a way? Or should I remove the duplicate time ranges myself?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an HKSampleQuery and account for overlapping samples. There is no HealthKit API that computes aggregate values for HKCategorySampleS.